# Using $var in $array

Tags: php, arrays, var

I need to use a var in an array:

```
$var = "abcd";
array( 'Bla: bla', 'Blo: $var', 'Bli: bli');
```

I'm totally noob at php and google has not answered me...

Thanks,

Comment: Variable interpolation only works in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, you can use double quotes. Or you can technically use concatenation.

**Double Quotes**

```
array( 'Bla: bla', "Blo: $var", 'Bli: bli');
```

**Concatenation**

```
array( 'Bla: bla', 'Blo: ' . $var, 'Bli: bli');
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can use double quotes or concatenation.  You can also use `=>` and leave the variable outside of the quotes.  For example:

```
$var = "blah";

$tester = array("boo"=>$var);

echo $tester["boo"];  // results in blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes `""`

```
array( 'Bla: bla', "Blo: $var", 'Bli: bli');
                   ^         ^
```